# How to edit a div inside PHP using CSS

Tags: php, css

How do I edit the three div's using CSS so that the result will be a table [like the following picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0ZA4.png)  (but in a better way. I created that table using Microsoft Word)

[image]

```
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "hangman";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `credits`");
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo "<div>Created By: ".$result["author_name"]."<br></div>";
            echo "<div>Contact: ".$result["author_email"]."<br></div>";
            echo "<div>Description: ".$result["description"]."</div>";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: Tables don't just get automagically created using CSS. Change your divs to tables instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "hangman";
    ?>
      <table>
          <td>Created By</td>
          <td>Contact</td>
          <td>Description</td>
<?php
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `credits`");
            $stmt->execute();

            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$result["author_name"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result["author_email"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$result["description"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $conn = null;
    ?>
</table>
```

I think you asking this. Try above code.

Comment: Can you please accept this as answer @LybinPeterBabu

Comment: You seem to be missing some `<tr>`'s there.